# Visual Studio "Immediate Window" vs "Interactive Window"

Tags: python, visual-studio

In Visual Studio what are the differences between the "Immediate Window" and the "Interactive Window" aka "Python Debug Interactive"?

It seems, in the Immediate Window I am able to evaluate expressions but cannot assign them. However in the Interactive Window I can do both.

What exactly are the differences between these two windows?
What is happening behind the scene when I evaluate an expression in Immediate Window and why can't I assign values to variables?

## Immediate Window

```
# I can evaluate expressions, eg  
1 + 2    
3  
np.array([0, 1])  
array([0, 1])  

# But I cannot assign variables  
x = np.array([0, 1])  
SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 3, 'x = np.array([0, 1])'))
```

## Interactive Window

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> np.array([0, 1])
array([0, 1])
>>> 
>>> x = np.array([0, 1])
>>> x
array([0, 1])
>>>
```

Edit: I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 and Python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interactive window provides you with a full python command line shell, i.e. it is the same as running python from a command window and then working in that python window. Basically use it as a sandbox for quick prototyping, expression evaluation or whatever else you'd normally do from the python command line.

The immediate window is used for debugging your current project. For example, set a break point somewhere in your project, and then when your application hits that breakpoint you can use the immediate window to evaluate expressions within the context of your running project. The code you write in the immediate window will have access to all the in-scope variables/methods, etc.

The immediate window behaves differently depending on the version of Visual Studio you are using. In versions earlier than VS 2017 you could do almost anything in the immediate window, e.g. assignments worked in all cases, but from VS 2017 onwards the underlying debugger has changed and now the immediate window is limited to pretty much expression evaluation only.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I understand that unlike the Interactive window, the Immediate window will have context of variables in scope but when I evaluate expressions in the Immediate Window, it still invokes the same Python interpreter as the Interactive window, doesn't it? So why shouldn't it be able to assign variables? (I am using VS 2019 in case it matters)